# I want to display two different font sizes of text in a composite image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Why do I want to display two different font sizes of text in a composite image, but only the first is displayed?

```
convert \( -resize "1000x1000^" -blur 50x5 "https://example.com/origin.jpg" -extent 1000x1000 -background none -fill "yellow" -colorize 40 \) \
  \( -font /var/hoge.otf -annotate +0-250 -background none -fill white -pointsize 80 -size 850x caption:"First line text in large font size" \) \
  \( -font /var/hoge.otf -annotate +0+250 -background none -fill white -pointsize 60 -size 850x caption:" Second line of text in small font size" \) \
  -gravity center -compose over -composite /var/output.jpg
```

---

Can't the annotate and caption options be used at the same time?

Comment: Your attempt has rather a lot of issues - outdated version, outdated ordering, unnecessary repetition of settings, confused mixture of `-annotate` and `caption:`, unexpected compositing... Maybe you could present a simpler example that doesn't include images we don't have and that also includes a diagram of what you are hoping to get output as a result.

Comment: Can't the annotate and caption options be used at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want to do in Imagemagick.  You do not need caption: and you do not need parentheses processing, just chaining of commands.  I have corrected your syntax ordering and modified your command a little to add -gravity center before -annotate. I also changed the font to something that I have and the fill color to black for the text to make it show more clearly.

```
convert "https://imagemagick.org/image/wizard.png" -resize "1000x1000^" -blur 50x5 -extent 1000x1000 -background none -fill "yellow" -colorize 40 \
-font /Users/fred/Fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf -background none -fill black -pointsize 60 -gravity center -annotate +0-250 "First line text in large font size" \
-font /Users/fred/Fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf -background none -fill black -pointsize 40 -gravity center -annotate +0+250 "Second line of text in small font size" \
output.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you very much.